# Download file and check file version in android

Tags: android

I am trying to download file from my server and then save them to sd card.

Now I am not asking for how to download them but I have other problems:

1 How about user exit my application during the download

When the user click the `Download` button, I will show a `ProcessDialog` with two button "Cancel" and "Do in Background".

If user click "Cancel" this is rather simple, stop the download.

But when user click "Do in the Background", I will dismiss the Dialog, but the download task(AsyncTask) will keeping work.

Now I wonder what will happen if user then exit my application?

2 File version check

In my application, I will check my server to see if the local file(at the sd card) is the latest, if not, then I will tell user to download the latest file.

Now I wonder is there a good idea to do the version checking?

I use the "last modified date" at the moment, but I am not sure if this is the best idea.

I wonder if we can add some tag to the file to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you use service download file so that if user exit app that will be downloading.

2.I also use "last modified date" to check my file. I think that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, if you want to do something in background even if the user exits, do it in a service not activity. If you are doing chunked download using the *Range* header of HTTP, then it would be quite easy to pass the job to the service. But I suggest you start the download thread in your service in the first place.

For your second question. There are lots of ways to do version check, using **last modified date** works but might come into error if some other application touches that file. You can save some version identifier in the database or shared preference or just in a file. If your file isn't too big you can just compare file hash (like doing an MD5 or CRC).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you do it correctly, downloading from the server will continue to occur.  For in the background check these links out...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
-and-
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

As for your other issue.  Last modified date should be fine if you want the user to get the latest whenever it is modified.  Which makes sense.